# Can Android NFC enabled act as an NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

Can an Android device that has NFC capabilites for example Galaxy SIII
act as an NFC or RFID card that can be read using another NFC Reader ? Not by an android device just another any general type NFC card reader ?

also Can the Android read NFC cards ? if yes - of any type ? can it read RFID ?

Comment: This appears to be a question about device capabilities, and not a programming question per se.

Comment: I'm asking this cause I need to develop an NFC app that emulates NFC cards.
thnx

Comment: this is not purely a question about device capabilities. there is valuable information about this question in the Android API docs, specifically http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html

Comment: @mfrankli: Many devices capabilities can be programmed.  That doesn't make this question any better.  To the OP: How about showing us some of your code, and being more specific about what your problem is?

Comment: nvm .. thnx for the hint anyway.

Comment: I'm not saying it's question of the year or anything, but my (obviously irrelevant) opinion was that it wasn't so irredeemably bad so as to justify your unilateral closing. Just fwiw (i.e., very little).

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. And the answers is, no, software card emulation is not possible in stock Android. It is however doable on CyanogenMod with some limitations. You can emulate 14443-4 cards, but not anything that works on a lower level such as MIFARE, etc. Details: http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod9-1-and-simplytapp and http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/10/emulating-pki-smart-card-with-cm91.html